# Understanding memory usage of this Haskell program

Tags: haskell, memory, haskell-pipes

I should preface this with saying I'm very much a beginner with Haskell and the pipes library, and I would like to understand what is causing the high memory usage of this program in the `test` function.

Specifically in the fold that produces `r1` value in `test` I'm seeing a build up of MyRecord values until the final result is produced, unless `deepseq` is used. On my sample data set of ~ 500000 lines / ~ 230 MB the memory usage grows beyond 1.5 GB.

The fold that produces `r2` value runs in constant memory.

What I would like to understand is:

1) What could be causing the build of MyMemory values in the first fold, and why using `deepseq` would fix it? I was very much throwing things at it at random until arriving at using `deepseq` to achieve constant memory usage but would like to understand why it works. Can constant memory usage be achieved without using `deepseq` while still producing the same result type of Maybe Int?

2). What is different for the second fold causing it not to exhibit the same issue?

I know that if I were to work with just integers instead of a tuples I could use the builtin `sum` function from Pipes.Prelude but I will eventually want to process the second element that contains any parsing errors.

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Test where

import           Control.Arrow
import           Control.DeepSeq
import           Control.Monad
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Function
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Monoid
import           Data.Text (Text)

import           Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Aeson as PA (DecodingError(..))
import qualified Pipes.Aeson.Unchecked as PA
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Pipes.Group as PG
import qualified Pipes.Parse as PP
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

import           System.IO
import           Control.Lens
import qualified Control.Foldl as Fold

data MyRecord = MyRecord
  { myRecordField1 :: !Text
  , myRecordField2 :: !Int
  , myRecordField3 :: !Text
  , myRecordField4 :: !Text
  , myRecordField5 :: !Text
  , myRecordField6 :: !Text
  , myRecordField7 :: !Text
  , myRecordField8 :: !Text
  , myRecordField9 :: !Text
  , myRecordField10 :: !Int
  , myRecordField11 :: !Text
  , myRecordField12 :: !Text
  , myRecordField13 :: !Text
  } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance FromJSON MyRecord where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    MyRecord <$> o .: "field1" <*> o .: "field2" <*> o .: "field3" <*>
    o .: "field4" <*>
    o .: "field5" <*>
    o .: "filed6" <*>
    o .: "field7" <*>
    o .: "field8" <*>
    o .: "field9" <*>
    (read <$> o .: "field10") <*>
    o .: "field11" <*>
    o .: "field12" <*>
    o .: "field13"
  parseJSON x = fail $ "MyRecord: expected Object, got: " <> show x

instance ToJSON MyRecord where
    toJSON _ = undefined

test :: IO ()
test = do
  withFile "some-file" ReadMode $ \hIn
  {-

      the pipeline is composed as follows:

      1 a producer reading a file with Pipes.ByteString, splitting chunks into lines,
        and parsing the lines as JSON to produce tuples of (Maybe MyRecord, Maybe
        ByteString), the second element being an error if parsing failed

      2 a pipe filtering that tuple on a field of Maybe MyRecord, passing matching
        (Maybe MyRecord, Maybe ByteString) downstream

      3 and a pipe that picks an Int field out of Maybe MyRecord, passing (Maybe Int,
        Maybe ByteString downstream)

      pipeline == 1 >-> 2 >-> 3

      memory profiling indicates the memory build up is due to accumulation of
      MyRecord "objects", and data types comprising their fields (mainly
      Text/ARR_WORDS)

  -}
   -> do
    let pipeline = f1 hIn >-> f2 >-> f3
    -- need to use deepseq to avoid leaking memory
    r1 <-
      P.fold
        (\acc (v, _) -> (+) <$> acc `deepseq` acc <*> pure (fromMaybe 0 v))
        (Just 0)
        id
        (pipeline :: Producer (Maybe Int, Maybe PB.ByteString) IO ())
    print r1
    hSeek hIn AbsoluteSeek 0
    -- this works just fine as is and streams in constant memory
    r2 <-
      P.fold
        (\acc v ->
           case fst v of
             Just x -> acc + x
             Nothing -> acc)
        0
        id
        (pipeline :: Producer (Maybe Int, Maybe PB.ByteString) IO ())
    print r2
    return ()
  return ()

f1
  :: (FromJSON a, MonadIO m)
  => Handle -> Producer (Maybe a, Maybe PB.ByteString) m ()
f1 hIn = PB.fromHandle hIn & asLines & resumingParser PA.decode

f2
  :: Pipe (Maybe MyRecord, Maybe PB.ByteString) (Maybe MyRecord, Maybe PB.ByteString) IO r
f2 = filterRecords (("some value" ==) . myRecordField5)

f3 :: Pipe (Maybe MyRecord, d) (Maybe Int, d) IO r
f3 = P.map (first (fmap myRecordField10))

filterRecords
  :: Monad m
  => (MyRecord -> Bool)
  -> Pipe (Maybe MyRecord, Maybe PB.ByteString) (Maybe MyRecord, Maybe PB.ByteString) m r
filterRecords predicate =
  for cat $ \(l, e) ->
    when (isNothing l || (predicate <$> l) == Just True) $ yield (l, e)

asLines
  :: Monad m
  => Producer PB.ByteString m x -> Producer PB.ByteString m x
asLines p = Fold.purely PG.folds Fold.mconcat (view PB.lines p)

parseRecords
  :: (Monad m, FromJSON a, ToJSON a)
  => Producer PB.ByteString m r
  -> Producer a m (Either (PA.DecodingError, Producer PB.ByteString m r) r)
parseRecords = view PA.decoded

resumingParser
  :: Monad m
  => PP.StateT (Producer a m r) m (Maybe (Either e b))
  -> Producer a m r
  -> Producer (Maybe b, Maybe a) m ()
resumingParser parser p = do
  (x, p') <- lift $ PP.runStateT parser p
  case x of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just (Left _) -> do
      (x', p'') <- lift $ PP.runStateT PP.draw p'
      yield (Nothing, x')
      resumingParser parser p''
    Just (Right b) -> do
      yield (Just b, Nothing)
      resumingParser parser p'
```

Comment: Check out the haskell tag info section and please post how you're compiling and running your binary

Comment: Because `seq (Just undefined) = ()` but `seq (undefined :: Int) () = undefined`

Comment: Consider `forceMaybe Nothing = Nothing; forceMaybe x@(Just !_) = x`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments everyone! If I understand what is being said the issue is due to accumulating the result in a Maybe, and the folding function creating a dependency on, or a reference to, MyRecord values. Until the result of the whole fold is demanded the intermediate values won't be evaluated beyond a constructor of Maybe causing  MyRecord's to pile up. deepseq forces anything "hiding" in a Maybe and allows MyRecord's to be garbage collected. Would that be a fair assessment of what's happening?

Comment: By the way, you can use `P.sum (pipeline >-> P.map (fromMaybe 0 . fst))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs for `Pipes.foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.2.0/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:fold), the fold is strict. However,
the strictness is [implemented with `$!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.2.0/docs/src/Pipes-Prelude.html#fold) which only forces evaluation
to WHNF - weak head normal form. WHNF is enough to fully evaluate a simple
type like an Int, but it isn't strong enough to completely evaluate a more
complex type like a `Maybe Int`.

Some examples:

```
main1 = do
  let a = 3 + undefined
      b = seq a 10
  print b                -- error: Exception: Prelude.undefined

main2 = do
  let a = Just (3 + undefined)
      b = seq a 10
  print b                -- no exception
```

In the first case the variable `acc` is a `Just` of a large thunk - the summation of all of the elements. On each iteration the variable `acc`
goes from `Just a` to `Just (a+b)` to `Just (a+b+c)` etc. The addition
is not being performed during the fold - it's only being done at the
very end. The large memory usage comes from storing this growing summation
in memory.

In the second case the summation is reduced each iteration by `$!` to a simple Int.

Besides using `deepseq` you can also use `force`:

```
force x = x `deepseq` x
```

and as [mentioned in the deepseq docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.2.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:force), combined with ViewPatterns you
can create an pattern which will fully evaluate a function argument:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

...
P.fold
  (\(force -> !acc) (v,_) -> (+) <$> acc <*> pure (fromMaybe 0 v))
  (Just 0)
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you @ErikR Am I correct in thinking that a build up of those thunks in the fold accumulator would also [cause  MyRecord's not to be released](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354139/understanding-memory-usage-of-this-haskell-program#comment66042269_39354139)?

Comment: Yes, because the summation contains references to your MyRecord values through calls to `myRecordField10`.